# Как узнать, является ли список или массив пустым

Tags: c#

Каким образом можно узнать, что в списке или массиве не содержится ни одного элемента?

Comment: У List<T> есть свойство Count, а у массива Length

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, не забудьте отметить его галочкой как верный.

Comment: @rdorn да, конечно

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Проверяйте свойство  `Length` массива или `Count` списка.

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
if(array.Length == 0) Console.WriteLine("Массив пуст.");

var list = new List<int>();
if(list.Count == 0) Console.WriteLine("Список пуст.");
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH, Пожалуйста!